# Creating New Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to create a new project, but when I click "Create New Project" it takes me to a window about choosing additional libraries and frameworks and then a huge empty box that says "Command Line App." How can I get to the window that lets me configure my project and choose the API and layout and such? [image]screenshot of the first window that opens:

Comment: put the image here please

Comment: I edited to include a screenshot

Comment: You dont have the android sdk installed.

Comment: I was able to get to the desired window earlier today, but it isn't working anymore. Do i have to redownload everything?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the first time you use android studio? Which version are you using?
When you installed it, did it throw any error?

You can try checking [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) which demonstrates how to configure it.

Comment: This is my first day using it, but I was able to get to the desired window earlier. It worked initially, then when I deleted the project to start over, I couldn't get to the desired window anymore. I'm using the latest version, and I got a bunch of plugin errors.

Comment: maybe your SDK installation was broken, in that case, you can try to do this fix http://nlopez.io/how-to-fix-a-broken-android-studio-sdk-installation/

Comment: Excellent! So did you repaired the SDK or what else did you do?